# xpath to grab selected elements

Tags: xpath

say i have :

```html
<pages>
    <author>Me</author>
    <copyright>me inc. 2015,</copyright>
    <lastUpdate>2/1/1999</lastUpdate>

    <Home>--------------------</Home>
    <About>--------------------</About>
    <Contact>------------------</Contact>

</pages>
```

i want two different xpath expressions that: 1. grabs all element between pages and home. 
that is, author, copyright, lastUpdate and Home.

2.grabs all element between pages and Contact
excluding Home. that is author, copyright, lastUpdated
and About.

any guide please ?

Comment: You are not using [stack snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) correctly. The powers that run the site are too stupid or lazy to fix the misue problem. I provided a bug report to get it fixed, but some members were too stupid to leave it alone. They closed it as a dup of a discussion. Obviously, a discussion got nothing done because the problem is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. //pages/*[(name() = 'Home')  or following-sibling::Home]

2. //pages/*[not(name() = 'Home')]
```

Comment: But why is //pages/*[ (name() = 'Home')   or following-sibling::Home] reporting Array ( [copyright] => me inc. 2015, )  upon print_r() ?

Comment: it must have  `<author>  <copyright> <lastUpdate> <Home> `

Comment: unfortunately not. i did a foreach loop, echoed the $key and only had copyright. what's the problem  with expression 1 ?